# How to add template-independent global css

Tags: css, global-configuration

I am setting up a Joomla 3 site and want to use custom global CSS which is template independent. The reason why I need this is that the admin of the site will need to change the template in use. I am setting up a few CSS styles which will need to be retained irrespective of the template in use.

Can some one tell me how to do this.

PS: I am relatively new to Joomla, so, please keep it in mind.

Comment: How template are you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, you can import a CSS file using a plugin which will inject the file into the `<head>` when it's being rendered.

I developed a [small plugin](http://joomjunk.co.uk/products/custom-assets.html) some time ago which allows you to import as many custom CSS or JS files.

You can also find others on the Joomla Extensions Directory under the [Coding & Scripts Integration](http://extensions.joomla.org/category/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration) category

Answer (score -1):

In protostar template:

- Create file in `/template/protostar/css/custom.css`
- Add in file `/template/protostar/index.php` after line ~44.

  ```
  $doc->addStyleSheet($this->baseurl . '/templates/' . $this->template . '/css/custom.css');
  ```

Comment: OP asked for a `global CSS which is template independent`. This solution would have to be implemented in each template :) In addition, `component.php` is a special file used to output the component part only (for print etc.), without any other content. In any case your code should be added to `index.php`.